cudafe++ died with status 0xc0000409 when switching to c++20 for nvcc
When I switch nvcc from using c++17 to c++20 through std flag, I get this error:

cudafe++ died with status 0xc0000409

All compiles and works as expected with 17, but when I switch to c++20, my compilation fails with the cryptic error.
I am running:

CUDA Toolkit v12.5
MVSC 17.10.1

Compiling host code with c++20 and passing c++17 flag to nvcc also works, and all my unit tests pass, but somehow, when I switch the nvcc flag, the compilation crashes.
What causes this behavior?
P.S.:

no heavy use of templates, basically just to switch loops on and off
no fancy options passed to nvcc also disabled them to see if they are causing issues
I do a clean build in between the attempts and delete any cached files


The error says stack buffer overrun https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000409

Report this as a bug to Nvidia. It is unlikely you will be able to get help here about closed source compiler internals

CUDA 12.5 Update 1 resolves the issue.

release notes
NVIDIA Forum
Download


You can accept your answer to mark the question as answered. It's the checkmark to the upper left of the answer.
