Trouble compiling a CUDA executable in CLion
I'm trying to compile a very basic program in CUDA. However, when I hit build in CLion, I get the following error message:
[1/3] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cu.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cu.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v12.5\bin\nvcc.exe -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler   -D_WINDOWS -Xcompiler=" /EHsc" -Xcompiler=" -Ob0 -Od /RTC1" -std=c++20 "--generate-code=arch=compute_52,code=[compute_52,sm_52]" -Xcompiler=-MDd -Xcompiler=-Zi -MD -MT CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cu.obj -MF CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cu.obj.d -x cu -rdc=true -c F:\data\code\clion\test\main.cu -o CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cu.obj -Xcompiler=-FdCMakeFiles\test.dir\,-FS
Compilation aborted.
main.cu
nvcc error   : 'cudafe++' died with status 0xC0000409 
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

My code looks like:
// main.cu
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
}

and my CMakeLists.txt is
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(test CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test main.cu)

set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

If it's any help, these are my build settings: 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The compiler's crashing not much you can do about that other than updating to the latest version and reporting the bug to Nvidia

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudacompile-nvcc-error-cudafe-died-with-status-0xc0000409/260651 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78586741/cudafe-died-with-status-0xc0000409-when-switching-to-c20-for-nvcc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78644379/cuda-12-5-with-visual-studio-2022-v17-10-3-not-working

That's unfortunate, thanks for helping anyway though.

Your use of Clion is irrelevant.
